# how to return data if catgory have at least three families

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables with relationship..every category have family or more

1-product_category

2-family

i want to select all categories and families joined if category have at least three families
in family table

i try this but it doesn't work..something wrong with count()

```
SELECT
 COUNT(fa_name) as count,
  d_family.*,
  d_product_type_category.pt_name
FROM d_family
  INNER JOIN d_product_type_category
    ON d_family.fa_id = d_product_type_category.pt_id
  where (count > 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. the aggregated column must be filtered by having clause not by where clause

```
SELECT
 COUNT(fa_name) as count,
  d_family.*,
  d_product_type_category.pt_name
FROM d_family
  INNER JOIN d_product_type_category
    ON d_family.fa_id = d_product_type_category.pt_id
group by <add all non-aggregated columns in the select clause>
  having (count > 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

use "And" operation on your where clause